# Can Maven ask the user for values and enter them into a file?

Tags: maven, configuration

I have a lot of config files that values have to change in. I would like to know if someone runs the "package" command can it ask for some values and insert them into my project files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use maven `-P` to select a maven profile and in turn selec the property files for it.

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>dev</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <resource.prefix>dev</resource.prefix>
        </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>prod</id>
        <properties>
            <resource.prefix>prod</resource.prefix>
        </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

Now access your resource file as `${resource.prefix}_config.properties`. So when the profile is prod, the resource file `prod_config.properties` will be taken.

Answer (score 3):

Better Approach would be have different property/config file depending upon environment.

1. Prod
2. Dev

Keep the two set of values in two different file. At times specify the file name.

Comment: Depending on the use case - yes, this is how many Maven projects are done.  You can also put the values directly in your pom.xml as properties that are activated by profiles and filtered into the configuration files.

Answer (score 1):

For 90% of build tasks, there's Maven. For everything else, there's [maven-antrun-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/).

I suggest creating a custom ant script (which can be embedded in your `pom.xml`) that prompts for user input and writes out your config files using the [Ant Input Task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/input.html)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot really make maven prompt for input unless you do some ant stuff suggested by [noahz](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12413124/can-maven-ask-the-user-for-values-and-enter-them-into-a-file/12413212#12413212).

What you can do if you don't want to play around with Profiles is to use properties in your pom file.

Example:

```
<project>
    <groupId>abc</groupId>
    <artifactId>def</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <myProperty>someValue</myProperty>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                ...
                <configuration>
                    <outputDir>${myProperty}</outputDir>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

You can use the property wherever you want within the pom file and you can even use the property when filtering resources.

The property could be empty by default and then have a new value set from command line:

```
mvn package -DmyProperty=anotherValue
```

And the `anotherValue` would be propagated to wherever it is used in pom.

---

You can read about Maven Resource Filtering [here](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html).

If you place a file in `src/main/resources` it could be filtered with the above property:

`src/main/resources/important-stuff.properties`

```
some.nice.property = Nice!
some.variable.property = ${myProperty}
```

And this should be added to the pom:

```
<build>
    ...
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
        </resource>
    </resources>
    ...
</build>
```

The filtered `important-stuff.properties` would end up in `target/classes` and in the jar and look like this:

```
some.nice.property = Nice!
some.variable.property = anotherValue
```

Resource filtering is really handy.